# DBT and K8s kiling prematurely

Tags: kubernetes, dbt

I'm running dbt on kubernetes via airflow. I have a task that is running nightly

```bash
dbt snapshot --select tag:frequency:nightly
```

What's interesting is that this pod is failing with an OOMKilled status at the very very tail end of the job. I get the message "Finished running 22 snapshots in 0 hours 0 minutes and 49.41 seconds (49.41s)" and then it immediately gets killed.

When I run it on my local machine, it runs successfully and prints the additional "Completed successfully Done. PASS=22 WARN=0 ERROR=0 SKIP=0 TOTAL=22".

I've amped up the memory for the pod to over 15 GB, which is way too much for the job and it still happens, so something is clearly amiss. Any help would be great.